# separate each letter with jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I separate each letter of a paragraph?

current html

```
<div id="news">news flash</div>
```

result should be like this

```
<div id="news">
<span>n</span><span>e</span><span>w</span><span>s</span><span>&nbsp;</span>
<span>f</span><span>l</span><span>a</span><span>s</span><span>h</span>
</div>
```

So that I could make animation effect to each letter as we do in flash or with image ready.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
$('#news').html(function(_,html){
    return html.split('').map(function(letter){
       return '<span>'+letter+'</span>'
    }).join('');
})
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/UhUnIrU/3/)

Comment: Don't we need to join? `return html.split('').map(function(letter){
       return '<span>'+letter+'</span>'
    }).join('')`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko It's cleaner but you don't *need* to : the `html` function, when you pass an argument which isn't a string calls `append` which calls the internal `domManip` function which deals with an array by appending the different elements. Of course that's not documented so it's better to add the `.join('')` ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
var txt = $("#news").html();
var spantxt="";
for(var i =0;i<txt.length;i++){
    spantxt+="<span>"+txt[i]+"</span>";
 }
$("#news").html(spantxt);
```